# How to uninstall teamviewer deb v10.0.036281 from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: uninstall

I installed teamviewer deb v10.0.036281 which is a 32bit?64bit Multi architecture one, it didn't worked well, so I tried to uninstall by using `sudo apt-get remove teamv` but got this reply

```
E: Unable to locate package teamv
```

am having Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit one

Answer (score 96):

First, use the command

```
dpkg -l | grep team
```

The full package name should show up in the output on the list of installed applications. Find it and use the name listed. I believe it should look like this:

```
sudo apt purge teamviewer
```

or, if you want to use a wild card, you can use something like this instead:

```
sudo apt remove "teamview*"
```

However, be careful when using a wildcard so you don't unintentionally uninstall something you want to keep. Always review the list of packages to be removed before selecting Y.

Answer (score 10):

The command below showed the full package name as teamviewer-host:

```
dpkg -l | grep team
```

I was able to remove it finally using:

```
sudo apt-get remove teamviewer-host
```

Comment: For xhubuntu this solution works fine

Answer (score 9):

If you downloaded the .deb elsewhere (didn't install through apt-get) then you need to

```
sudo dpkg -r teamviewer
```

Comment: if it's a deb, it should be uninstallable through apt-get once it is installed regardless of how installation took place

Answer (score 4):

To remove Teamviewer, run

```
sudo apt-get remove teamviewer
```

Answer (score 3):

You could run

```
dpkg --remove --force-all teamviewer
```

Worked fine for me. Apt-get did not work giving me the following output:

```
apt-get remove teamviewer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package teamviewer:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

So using `dpkg` got me through this.

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
sudo aptitude remove teamviewer
```

If not installed aptitude, run:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Use only aptitude, he is best installer deb pkg.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have typed the package name correctly. Otherwise you are trying to uninstall the one which is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Type:
sudo apt-get remove teamv
and then hit tab and it should auto-complete.

and `The following packages will be REMOVED: teamviewer-host`