# apt-get purge - not working properly

Tags: 16.04, apt, teamviewer

I've been having really long shutdown times. Today I noticed Ubuntu was stuck on ending a `teamviewer` process. I don't use it anymore so I decided to remove it.

I tried from the Ubuntu software, but nothing happens.
I tried **`sudo apt-get purge teamviewer`** but nothing happens.

When I issue **`dpkg -l | grep team`**

```
ic  teamviewer6:i386     6.0.9380   i386         TeamViewer (Remote Control Application)
ii  teamviewer9:i386     9.0.225162 i386         TeamViewer (Remote Control Application)
```

The `teamviewer` icon is still available and it still works.

Is there something wrong with APT? I also tried resetting apt with below commands

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
$ sudo apt-get update**
```

I'm using UBUNTU 16.04 LTS

Any help appriciated

Comment: 1. teamviewer and teamviewer6:i386 / teamviewer9:i386 are different packages; 2. 16.04 LTS is EOL; 3. please learn markdown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall teamviewer deb v10.0.036281 from ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/565384/167115)

Answer (score 2):

16.04 is EOL which is off topic but this answer applies to all versions of Ubuntu.

The output of `dpkg -l | grep team` shows that the package names are `teamviewer6` and `teamviewer9`. To remove these packages, run the following command:

```
sudo apt purge teamviewer6 teamviewer9
```

That should work but if it doesn't, run the following:

```
sudo apt purge teamviewer6:i386 teamviewer9:i386
```

Comment: Yes that worked! Feeling a bit dumb, but happy now. Thanks!

Comment: @ColinAttard Hey, at least you learned something.